# Django Query - Filter - Aggregation - error if no value

Tags: django, aggregation

I get the below errors in my browser:

"Matching query does not exist"
"bad operand type for unary -: 'NoneType'"

I have the impression it is because I'm running Aggregations on Querysets.Though when the filter returns nothing. The aggregation doesn't return '0' but an error. Can this be? I believe it is this way because when I add a single figure (for instance 1) it works. How can I solve it? Below example from my code (aggregation).

many thanks !

```
calcul1 = Flow.objects.filter(name__slug=nameslug).filter(type='Call').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

calcul2 = Flow.objects.filter(type='Dist').aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']

calcul3 = BaseNV.objects.filter(name__slug=nameslug).values('amount').latest('date')['amount']
```

Comment: `.latest('date')` does not do any aggregation, but returns  a model instance which would typically not permit key access via `['amount']`. Other than that aggregations do return `None` if the underlying queryset is empty, so you could do sth like `MyModel.objects....aggregate(...)['sum'] or 0` if you want do further calculations.

Comment: It's not clear which line causes which error, can you be more precise? But in general you should never subscript (`['sum']`) a dictionary if you're not sure the dictionary isn't None and has that key.